# Confused about Kafka Consumer Properties

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm a bit confused by some of the consumer API configuration properties. It seems as though they either conflict, or cancel each other out. Can someone help me understand the difference between the following keys.

**Definitions**:

`fetch.max.bytes`: Maximum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request
`max.partition.fetch.bytes`: Max amount of data per-partition the server will return
`max.poll.records`: The maximum number of records returned in a single call to poll()

**Example**:
`fetch.max.bytes`: 30000 (30kb)
`max.partition.fetch.bytes`: 20000000 (20mb)
`max.poll.records`: 1000

To me it seems like the consumer definition above is saying it can accept up to 20mb of data/partition, but then only specifying max bytes of 30kb which doesn't make sense. Max poll records also seems to limit data intake since it's possible 1000 is too low or too high based on the size of each record.

Answer (score 2):

`fetch.max.bytes` and `max.partition.fetch.bytes` are fields of [Fetch requests](https://kafka.apache.org/protocol#The_Messages_Fetch) sent to Kafka brokers. They respectively determine the maximum size of the Fetch response the broker will send and the maximum size of data per partition the broker can return. It's the broker that uses these values to compute a Fetch response.

On the other hand, `max.poll.records` is a client-side only configuration. It determines how many records a call to `poll()` can return.

The consumer will fetch records in the background and buffer them so records are ready when `poll()` is called.

These settings allow for example to fetch records in batches, which is more efficient, but still pass them to the Consumer application in small chunks or even individually depending on the processing its doing.

Comment: Got it. I understand `max.poll.records` a bit better from your answer. 

What's the use of specifying both `fetch.max.bytes` and `max.partition.fetch.bytes` in the same config? I get what they do individually, but still confused why you would specify both.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly set them as they have sensible default values. These settings are available if you have a specific use case that would benefit from different values, for example a very small or large number of partitions assigned to each consumer and the need to control precisely how much data is returned by each Fetch response.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for clarifying. I recently ran into an issue where a broker i was consuming data from had a very large `fetch.max.bytes` which led to OOM issues which forced me to set them to reasonable values to protect the consumer.